# Laravel 403 Forbidden when uploading site

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have uploaded my site to 1and1 (for a client not my choice) and I had to put the website in a subfolder off of root so basically:

```
-/
 -/subfolder
   -/app
   /vendor
   /public
   /everything else laravel has
```

and I successfully edited the domain to point to the public folder.

However, when I try to go to `www.website.com` it returns an 403 forbidden error. I can go to other pages `www.website.com/coolstuff` with zero issues. I can even pull up the home page by typing `www.website.com/index.php`

So, I thought it was my .htaccess file and I edited it according to other peoples issues related to 1and1 and laravel and I still get the same problem.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
</IfModule>
```

So not sure of another way to edit this to get it to work. Or, if it could be another issue or setting within 1and1.

Comment: Make sure the directory has read permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this at the top of your .htaccess file and see how it works for you.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Typically when you can access the index file directly but you can't without specifying it, your apache config may not have a directory index specified for index.php. So you will get a 403 forbidden because directory indexing is turned off and it thinks you don't have an index file.